# Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The Euclidean Algorithm is based on the move from a pair $(m,n)$, where $m>n$, to the pair $(m-n,n)$ which is then ordered so that the larger number is listed first. If we start from two numbers $a>b$ show that at every next stage the two obtained numbers are integral linear combinations of $a$ and $b$. Those are numbers of the form $ka+rb$ , where $k$ and $r$ are integers. Conclude that $\gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive integral linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried?

Comment: I'm just not even sure where to begin.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Begin by thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep subtracting $n$ until the first number becomes smaller than $n$ (assuming $n>0$, otherwise the greatest common divisor is $m$).

This is the “division with remainder”: $m=nq+r$, where $0\le r<n$.

Now, given $a>b>0$, we can proceed just like old Euclid did (with different terminology). Set $r_0=b$ and do the division like before:
$$
a=r_0q_1+r_1,\qquad 0\le r_1<r_0
$$
Note now that the pairs $(a,b)=(a,r_0)$ and $(r_0,r_1)$ have the same common divisors; we are done if $r_1=0$, otherwise we can repeat:
$$
r_0=r_1q_2+r_2,\qquad 0\le r_2<r_1
$$
and proceed in the same way until we get $0$ as remainder: this is certain to happen, because the successive remainders decrease. We even have a bound on the number of steps: it is $b$. Actually the bound can be refined, but we just need to know the algorithm stops.

At each stage, the greatest common divisor of the pair $(r_{k-1},r_k)$ is the same as the greatest common divisor of the pair $(r_k,r_{k+1})$. So if we say that in $n$ steps we find the last nonzero remainder, that is, $r_{n-1}=r_nq_{n+1}+0$, the considerations above tell us that $r_n$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Now we want to get as fast as possible that $r_n=as+bt$ for some integers $s$ and $t$. We can do by induction on $n$ (the number of steps for getting at the greatest common divisor).

If $n=0$, then $a=bq_1$ and so $b=\gcd(a,b)$ and $b=a\cdot0+b\cdot1$. Thus the base step is done.

Suppose $n>0$. We need to find a pair of numbers for which the algorithm takes $n-1$ steps. But we already have them: the algorithm from $A=b$ and $B=r_1$ proceeds in exactly the same way, with the only difference it takes one step less! Then the induction hypothesis gives us
$$
r_n=bs'+r_1t'
$$
for some integers $s'$ and $t'$. But the first step of the algorithm says $r_1=a-bq_0$, so
$$
r_n=bs'+(a-bq_0)t'=at'+b(s'-q_0t')
$$
and we are done with $s=t'$ and $t=s'-q_0t'$.

Now we have all the tools for characterizing the greatest common divisor as *the least positive integral linear combination of $a$ and $b$*.

We have proved that the greatest common divisor $d=\gcd(a,b)$ is an integral linear combination. Suppose $c=au+bv$ is a positive integral linear combination. Since $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$ for some integers $a'$ and $b'$, we have
$$
c=a'du+b'dv=d(a'u+b'v)
$$
and $a'u+b'v$ is positive, hence $a'u+b'v\ge1$. Therefore $c\ge d$.

Note that we have proved more: every (positive) integral linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,b)$. Note also that the Euclidean algorithm provides a way to compute *explicitly* the integers $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is by iteration. Notice, in each step the first larger number gets smaller. But, this cannot go on without end as numbers are finite. Consequently, there is a smallest number which the algorithm reaches. I'm not sure what you're asking generally so I'll illustrate the method for now:
\begin{align}
(16,10) &= (a,b) \\
(6,10) \mapsto (10,6) &= (b,a-b) \\
(4,6)\mapsto (6,4) &= (a-b, b-(a-b)) = (a-b,2b-a) \\
(2,4) \mapsto (4,2) &= (2b-a, (a-b)-(2b-a)) = (2b-a, 2a-3b) \\
\end{align}
Now that $2\mid 4$ I halt and observe $gcd(16,10)=2$ and $2 = 2a-3b$ or,
$2= 2(16)-3(10)$. Notice the "positive" refers to $2$ not the coefficients $k,r$ in the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination. Usually the euclidean algorithm based on remainders is faster, but here it's about the same:
\begin{align}
(16,10) &= (a,b) \\
(10, 6)&=(b,a-b) \\
(6, 4) &= (a-b,b-(a-b)) = (a-b,2b-a) \\
(4,2) &=(2b-a, a-b-(2b-a)) = (2b-a,2a-3b).
\end{align}

Comment: To prove conclusions about the gcd you need to have grasp of basic lemmas like $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$ implies $a \mid c_1b+c_2c$ for $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. If you look at what you do in the algorithm you'll see the divisor structure follows from these sort of lemmas. Anyway, first things first, be sure you understand the algorithm itself.